# Azman Obsolete? What is the new alternative to Azman?

Tags: c#, security, authorization, enterprise-library, azman

Is there a replacement for Azman, that is a new way to apply security. Previously we were using EntLib 3 and used Azman for our security and authorisation. However an article I read about the vision of EntLib 6.0 is to deprecate Security(*link below*), but there is no alternative specified. May someone please advise what the best method to handle security and authorization is now?

[Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2012/11/08/enterprise-library-6-0-vision-scope.aspx)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**edit:** Azman seems deprecated on Windows 2012 R2, see the first link

AzMan itself is NOT deprecated and is [available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897401.aspx) for modern versions of Windows, including Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8. What is deprecated is the EntLib’s Security Application Block which included a wrapper to AzMan. This is aligned with our [deprecation approach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2011/04/08/on-deprecation.aspx).

You have several options depending on your upgrade objectives:

1. Upgrade to EntLib5.0 which still includes the Security
   Application Block with AzMan wrapper.
2. Use AzMan directly.
3. Upgrade to EntLib 6, but take the source of AzMan wrapper from EntLib5.
4. Use claims-based authorization though that’s a very different model. For more info, I suggest you take a look at this [Guide to Claims-Based Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for replying me. I think will go for the Claims-Based Identity, although its a bit misty at the moment. I think it is the best for our scenario because we are using active directory services to manage our users.

Comment: We are still using Azman even for our new projects. Despite the advent of WIF there is still no direct replacement for AzMan (as far as I am aware) at this time.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of migrating to a claims-based approach, have a look at:

[Claims : Azman in the new claims-based world](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2016/04/claims-azman-in-new-claims-based-world.html).

Note Azman is deprecated as of Windows Server 2012 R2 and may be removed in subsequent versions.

Answer (score 0):

recovering this question, and kind of stuck. I have a WCF .Net framework 4.0 project that takes advantage of AzMan for authorization purposes.

We are thinking of migrating this project to .Net 6, but we need to keep using some sort of authorization with Active Directory, but AzMan is not an option nowadays.

What is a possible evolution in order to replace azman for this scenario?